# Can't get Solspace Tag Entries to work

Tags: solspace-tag

So I'm developing a site using [Solspace Tag](http://www.solspace.com/software/detail/tag/).  A little background... I have a site that displays tags in two places.  One global cloud tag in the footer, and another in an entries detail page (tags associated with that specific entry).  When a user clicks on a tag, they should be taken to a page that displays all entries with that particular tag. I've been trying to get the example from the documentation to work, but the page does not output anything.  The only thing in the template is the following tag pair.

```
{exp:tag:entries
    inclusive="yes"
    orderby="entry_date"
    sort="asc"
    limit="20"
    paginate="bottom"
}
    <h2>{title}</h2>
    <p>{body}</p>
{tag_paginate}
    <p>Page {tag_current_page} of {tag_total_pages}. {tag_pagination_links}</p>
{/tag_paginate}

{/exp:tag:entries}
```

Do I need to wrap this in an entries tag as well?

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news|reviews|etc"}{/exp:channel:entries}
```

What does work is {exp:tag:tag_name}. I can output the tag name based on the URL.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.  For anyone interested, the global footer along with the tags in the detail pages uses the `websafe_separator="-"` parameter, while the tag entries page (page that user lands on after they click on a tag" did not have this parameter in it.

More information can be found in the docs [here](http://www.solspace.com/docs/tag/entries/#websafe_separator).